# I have n spaces, in each space, I can place a number 0 through m. Writing a program to output all possible results. Need help :)

Tags: c++, permutation

The idea is, given an n number of spaces, empty fields, or what have you, I can place in either a number from 0 to m. So if I have two spaces and just 01 , the outcome would be:
(0 1)
(1 0)
(0 0)
(1 1)

if i had two spaces and three numbers (0 1 2) the outcome would be

(0 1)
(1 1)
(0 2)
(2 0)
(2 2)
(2 1)

and so on until I got all 9 (3^2) possible outcomes.

So i'm trying to write a program that will give me all possible outcomes if I have n spaces and can place in any number from 0 to m in any one of those spaces.

Originally I thought to use for loops but that was quickly shotdown when I realzed I'd have to make one for every number up through n, and that it wouldn't work for cases where n is bigger.

I had the idea to use a random number generator and generate a number from 0 to m but that won't guarantee I'll actually get all the possible outcomes.

I am stuck :(

Ideas?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: btw., you basically need two for loops, thats all that is needed. Correction, to account for n, it is easier with a recursive function, since you dont know what n is.

Comment: If you have 3 spaces and 10 numbers 0 to 9, can you output all 10^3 combinations?

Comment: I'm not looking for a final solution Mr. Roth. I'm looking for some guidance on how to tackle the problem or how to begin solving it. I have no method in place as of now because the two I originally though up wouldn't work.

I appreciate your second comment though. I had not though of recursion.

Comment: Here's a hint for the recursive solution. Say you have a function that can produce the result for n - 1 spaces. The solution for n spaces would be to prefix the solution for n-1 spaces with 0, then prefix the solution for n-1 spaces with 1, ..., prefix the solution for n-1 spaces with n

Comment: next_permutation works when you know what the elements in the spaces are, I don't MooingDuck

Thank you Bwmat , that helps :)

Comment: @neojb1989: Yeah, sorry about that.  I started reading the docs and realized that's completely the wrong thing.

Comment: You don't need (or want) recursion, nested loops or permutation generators for this. As @n.m. implied, what you have is simply an N digit number in base M. Count from 0 through M^N-1, and convert each in base M to get your result. If your symbols are something other than 0, 1, 2, ..., use each digit of the results to index into an array/vector of corresponding symbols.

Comment: base M just numbers in multiples of M right?

Comment: @neojb1989: Not sure I follow what you're asking. If you're asking whether base M restricts you to representing numbers that are multiples of M, then the answer is no (e.g., in normal base 10 number, you can certainly represent 7 or 23, neither of which is a multiple of 10).

Comment: OH, right, herp. Right, I'm going to go find out what base numbers actually mean. Never understood base or log too well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you will need is a starting point, ending point, and a way to convert from each state to the next state. For example, a recursive function that is able to add one number to the smallest pace value that you need, and when it is larger than the maximum, to increment the next larger number and set the current one back to zero.

Take this for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// This is just a function to print out a vector.
template<typename T>
inline ostream &operator<< (ostream &os, const vector<T> &v) {
    bool first = true;
    os << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size (); i++) {
        if (first) first = false;
        else os << " ";
        os << v[i];
    }
    return os << ")";
}

bool addOne (vector<int> &nums, int pos, int maxNum) {
    // If our position has moved off of bounds, so we're done
    if (pos < 0)
        return false;

    // If we have reached the maximum number in one column, we will
    // set it back to the base number and increment the next smallest number.
    if (nums[pos] == maxNum) {
        nums[pos] = 0;
        return addOne (nums, pos-1, maxNum);
    }

    // Otherwise we simply increment this numbers.
    else {
        nums[pos]++;
        return true;
    }
}

int main () {
    vector<int> nums;
    int spaces = 3;
    int numbers = 3;

    // populate all spaces with 0
    nums.resize (spaces, 0);

    // Continue looping until the recursive addOne() function returns false (which means we
    // have reached the end up all of the numbers)
    do {
        cout << nums << endl;    
    } while (addOne (nums, nums.size()-1, numbers));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically, after reading David Schwartz's post, the code does exactly what he describes. It picks a base case (where everything is zero), it then prints out that base case and increments it by 1 (the addOne() function). It will then keep printing out the result from addOne() until it has completed all possible combinations in all spaces.

Comment: I'm reading it now trying to understand. Thank your for linking this to his post. I think with both of these things I'll comprehend.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a task requires finding "all of" something, you should first try to do it in these three steps: Can I put them in some kind of order? Can I find the next one given one? Can I find the first?

So if I asked you to give me all the numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive, how would you do it? Well, it's easy because: You know a simple way to put them in order. You can give me the next one given any one of them. You know which is first. So you start with the first, then keep going to the next until you're done.

This same method applies to this problem. You need three algorithms:

1. An algorithm that orders the outputs such that each output is either greater than or less than every other possible output. (You don't need to code this, just understand it.)
2. An algorithm to convert any output into the next output and fail if given the last output. (You do need to code this.)
3. An algorithm to generate the first output, one less (according to the first algorithm) than every other possible output. (You do need to code this.)

Then it's simple:

1. Generate the first output (using algorithm 3). Output it.
2. Use the increment algorithm (algorithm 2) to generate the next output. If there is no next output, stop. Otherwise, output it.
3. Repeat step 2.

**Update**: Here are some possible algorithms:

Algorithm 1:

1. Compare the first digits of the two outputs. If one is greater than the other, that output is greater. If they are equal, continue
2. Repeat step on moving to successive digits until we find a mismatch.

Algorithm 2:

1. Start with the rightmost digit.
2. If this digit is not the maximum it can be, increment it and stop.
3. Are we at the leftmost digit? If so, stop with error.
4. Move the digit pointer left one digit.

Algorithm 3:

1. Set all digits to zero.

Comment: For algorithm 1, a possible ordering is like numbers are ordered.  So for your "two spaces and three numbers (0 1 2)" example, you get `(0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (2 0) (2 1) (2 2)`

Comment: That is hard to read at first glance, I'm going to keep going over it but for the little I get right now, I think you are a smart man.

Comment: could you explain algorithm 2 a little more?

Comment: @neojb1989: Each possible combination of `n` digits from `0-m` is equivalent to a number expressed in base `m+1`. So if `n` and `m` are both 2, and you have 9 results, these results are exactly equivalent to the numbers `0` through `8` expressed in base `4`.

Comment: @neojb1989: So algorithm 1 is basically "compare two numbers expressed in base `m+1`". Algorithm 2 is "increment a number in base `m+1`". And algorithm 3 is "express 0 in base `m+1`".

Comment: @KevinBallard: Exactly. You don't need to implement algorithm 2, just have it in mind when you implement algorithms 2 and 3.

Comment: Alright I think I can get this now. If not, I'll be back crying :P Thank you kindly for the help.

Comment: So ok, every time, in algorithm 2, that I would increment the rightmost digit, that would be a new output and I would save it somewhere correct?

Comment: @neojb1989: In the final implementation that uses algorithm 2, you'll output things where the description (under "Then it's simple") says "output it". Don't do it in algorithm 2 -- that algorithm just changes one value to the next value.

Comment: Ooooh ok. That makes more sense.

Comment: Holy crap ok I think I understand now> I ran Alex's program a few times and ok I think I get what it's doing.

Comment: And also how it relates to what you're saying. Wish I could select both of you as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> “i'm trying to write a program that will give me all possible outcomes if I have n spaces and can place in any number from 0 to m in any one of those spaces.”

Assuming an inclusive “to”, let R = m + 1.

Then this is isomorphic to outputting every number in the range 0 through R<sup>n</sup>-1 presented in the base R numeral system.

Which means one outer loop to count (for this you can use the C++ `++` increment operator), and an inner loop to extract and present the digits. For the inner loop you can use C++’ `/` division operator, and depending on what you find most clear, also the `%` remainder operator. Unless you restrict yourself to the three choices of R directly supported by the C++ standard library, in which case use the standard formatters.

Note that R<sup>n</sup> can get large fast.

So don't redirect the output to your printer, and be prepared to wait for a while for the program to complete.

Comment: Hmm...something strangely familiar sounding about this answer. :-) But +1 for posting a correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look up recursion. http://www.danzig.us/cpp/recursion.html

Basically it is a function that calls itself. This allows you to perform an N number of nested for loops.

Comment: I had not thought of recursion. Thank you :)

Comment: You don't actually need recursion to implement this.

Comment: Oh? Because what you had said sounded like you were suggesting something recursive as well @KevinBallard , I'll reread it.

Comment: @neojb1989: I went ahead and implemented a solution, which ended up being almost exactly how David suggested. It was purely iterative, not recursive.

Comment: I am trying to get a grasp on the other algorithms. Do any of them perform the task more efficiently than O(m^n)?